# Short hand (1 line statement) to initialize array of generics

Tags: java, generics

I was wondering, is there any short hand to initialize array of generic?

Currently, the way to initialize array of non generics is as follow.

```
String[] s = {
    "hello",
    "world"
};
```

However, it is **not possible** to perform the similar, for generics.

```
Call<FundamentalResponse> calls[] = {
    yearlyFundamentalResponseCall,
    quarterlyFundamentalResponseCall
};
```

Right now, I have to do it in several lines of code.

```
Call<FundamentalResponse> calls[] =  (Call<FundamentalResponse>[]) new Call[2];
calls[0] = yearlyFundamentalResponseCall;
calls[1] = quarterlyFundamentalResponseCall;
```

I was wondering, is there any one line statement to achieve same purpose?

Comment: You shouldn't mix arrays and generics in the first place. Use a List<Call<FundamentalResponse>>.

Comment: @JBNizet why not mix arrays and generics?

Comment: Generally speaking, it's better to avoid arrays in Java in the first place. Just use lists everywhere.

Comment: Use the full `= new Callable[]` syntax, with the raw type. But, also, **don't**.

Comment: You can't even create a generic array without using nasty tricks like using raw types. That makes your code unsafe. Besides, arrays are covariant whereas generics are invariants, so they don't share the same model. Arrays are discouraged in general. They're meant to be used in very low-level code, or to contain primitives (like bytes).

Comment: Sorry folks. I know the advantages of List. But I need array in my situation.

Comment: I would still advise building into a `List`, and then using `Arrays` Class to convert to array. If you(anyone reading) are using an array to maintain order you should invest some time into learning the fundamental difference between Classes based on asynchronous (like `Call`) vs synchronous architectures.

Comment: Simple answer, No. I think short initializer works like syntax sugar. In compile time it will try to replace short initializer with full one using reference type. In case Generic ref type as it's not possible to create generic array it throws CTE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
Call<FundamentalResponse>[] calls = (Call<FundamentalResponse>[]) new Call[] {
    yearlyFundamentalResponseCall,
    quarterlyFundamentalResponseCall
};
```

Comment: What a shame that I had missed out this syntax. Thanks for telling me.